# Creating new subsite in sharepoint 2013,site tempate

Tags: site-template, site-definition

While creating subsite, it will ask to choose tempalte. I would like to remove few template from the option eg. Community site. So that user should not create subsite with community site template. Please suggset easiest way of doing it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Site Settings --> Under Look and Feel --> Choose **Page Layouts and site templates**

Under Sub site templates, you can remove any templates you don't want from the right hand selection.

Comment: Hi,, If I want to do it for all site colletion. Plzz suggest

Comment: You will have to do it manually for each site collection, I'm afraid. If you are open to powershell script, try this http://sharepoint-community.net/forum/topics/can-i-use-powershell-to-update-the-subsite-templates-on